# dynamic bootstrap tabs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, tabs

I am trying to get rails to generate dynamic navigation tabs that refer to groups user is enrolled at. Basically, what I want to achieve is to dynamically have tabs named after groups that user is enrolled at (which is working fine) and then showing the content of each group by clicking on its tab (which is not working properly for some reason). The page loads data correctly but toggling between tabs doesn't work

Here is the code in the view

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <% current_user.group.each do |group| %>
            <li><a href="#<%= group.name %>" data-toggle="tab">
            <%=group.name %></a></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <% current_user.group.each do |group| %>
            <div class="tab-pane fade <%= 'in active' if current_user.group.first == group %>" id="<%=group.name%>">
              <% if current_user.group_feed(group.id).any? %>
                  <ol class="microposts">
                    <%= render current_user.group_feed(group.id) %>
                    <%= group.name %>
                  </ol>
              <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Have you included bootstrap js files?

Comment: Does `group.name` produce a valid html id attribute?

Comment: Turns out that this works perfectly as long as tab id is one word only, which seems a little odd for me. I guess it should have used group.id for tab id instead of group.name

Comment: I suppose that valid html id attribute should not be more than one word, correct?

Comment: Assuming `group.id` is an integer, it is an invalid html id.

Comment: Correct on the no more than one word.

Comment: I would dynamically create the html id from the name: `name.parameterize` should clear out any dodgy chars and spaces.

Comment: So if I can't use group.id or group.name as the tab id, how can I go around this for dynamic generation of tabs? any ideas? the only solution I can think of is adding a new attribute to group model but this does not seem the right way

Comment: I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `group.name` producing an invalid html id attribute.

html ids should not start with a number(numbers anywhere else are ok), and have no spaces. Example:

Invalid:

`1foo`
`aaa b`

Valid:

`foo1`
`aaa-b`

`group.name.parameterize` will remove any odd chars(@£$ etc) and replace spaces with `"-"` so use that.

You also want to make this unique as things with names like: `"foo"` and `"foo!"` will `parameterize` to the same thing: `"foo"`.

I'd go with:

`id="<%=(group.name.gsub(/[0-9]+/, "")+group.id.to_s).parameterize%>"`

This code, removes any number from the name(it only really applies at the start of the id) then adds the `id` on the end making it unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I can vote the answer up, until the moment I dont have enough reputation points to do so.